# Problem with e2e testing with NestJS TestingModule, GraphQL code first and TypeOrm

Tags: graphql, e2e-testing, nestjs

I'm in struggle since few days with **e2e testing** my **NestJS** application using **GraphQL** code first approach and **TypeOrm**.

I'm trying to create a **TestingModule** by injecting nestjs **GraphQLModule** with *autoSchemaFile* and I'm always getting the error "*Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named ...*".

Here a reproduction of my bug with minimal code:

`character.entity.ts`:

```js
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from 'type-graphql';

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Character {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Field(() => ID)
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    @Field()
    name: string;
}
```

`character.resolver.ts`:

```js
import { Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Character } from './models/character.entity';
import { CharacterService } from './character.service';

@Resolver(() => Character)
export class CharacterResolver {
    constructor(private readonly characterService: CharacterService) {}

    @Query(() => [Character], { name: 'characters' })
    async getCharacters(): Promise<Character[]> {
        return this.characterService.findAll();
    }
}
```

`character.module.ts`:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CharacterResolver } from './character.resolver';
import { CharacterService } from './character.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Character } from './models/character.entity';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Character])],
    providers: [CharacterResolver, CharacterService],
})
export class CharacterModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CharacterModule } from './character/character.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), GraphQLModule.forRoot({ autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql' }), CharacterModule],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {}
}
```

and finally: `character.e2e-spec.ts`:

```js
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CharacterModule } from '../src/character/character.module';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

describe('CharacterResolver (e2e)', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [
                TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
                GraphQLModule.forRoot({ playground: false, autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql' }),
                CharacterModule,
            ],
        }).compile();

        app = module.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();
    });

    it('should create testing module', () => {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });
});
```

And after running `npm run test:e2e`:

```
Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Character".

      at typeMapReducer (../node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:262:13)
          at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
      at new GraphQLSchema (../node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:145:28)
      at Function.generateFromMetadataSync (../node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:31:24)
      at Function.<anonymous> (../node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:16:33)
      at ../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:110:75
      at Object.__awaiter (../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:106:16)
      at Function.generateFromMetadata (../node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:15:24)
```

I don't find any other way to create a testing module with graphql code first approach on official doc or while googling... Am I missing something ?

Comment: Just set this up today and found the same issue. No clue what's leading to it. I can confirm the error occurs at the point: `app.init()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ormconfig.json` need to look like this:

```
  "entities": [
    "src/**/*.entity.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/migration/*.js"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration"
  }
```

I.e you need to specify the entities being in the `src`, not `dist` folder. If not TypeGraphQL will generate the schema for each resolver twice. To get the generate and run migration commands to work you would have to setup a different `ormconfig.json` for your development environment.